# OpenLayers - Updating initialize method of Class call

Tags: openlayers

I would like to update one of the variables in a vector layer class after the original call to the class

```
OpenLayers.Layer.Observations = OpenLayers.Class(
  OpenLayers.Layer.Vector, {
```

where one of the options is the initialize method:

```
initialize: function(name, displayStyle, options) {
```

It seems like you can't just override the initialize method...

```
var lyrObs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Observations("Observations",...

lyrObs.initialize(...)
```

Is there another way to update that initialize methods variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the source! There are many examples. What you need is something like this:

```
OpenLayers.Layer.Observations = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Layer.Vector, {
    initialize: function(…) {
        OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        // Do what you want here
    }
});
```

Comment: What is this statement doing? OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);     It's found within the initialize method, but seems to be calling itself with arguments that come from the blue.

Comment: the `initialize` method of Observations class, will call the *parent* `initialize` method (the one of Layer.Vector) within *its* scope (`this`, first argument) and with the same arguments that it receive (`arguments`, second argument, a javascript reserved keyword to get function arguments). Once you have called parent’s method, you can do your specific stuff. HTH…

Comment: Thanks tonio, that helped me understand the statement: OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments); It doesn't seem like you could call that outside of the class though right? What I'm trying to do is re-run the initialize method outside of the class after the class has already been instantiated, i.e. after the intialize method has already run. Essentially running it a second time with a different argument when a user switches a select box. Thanks for helping so far, I think I'm getting close.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing it this way?

```
lyrObs.prototype.initialize = function...
```

Also, you can overide any of the layer's properties like `lyrObs.style = ...` or `lyrObs.data = ...`

Comment: Ok, so you can override the initialize method :-), but what if I just want to "re-run" the initialize method after one of the layer's properties were updated? For example, I change lyrObs.style and it is within the initialize method. Is there away just to call it again without having to rewrite it? Thanks for your help!